# How to count the number of clicks on href tag?

Tags: html, href, tel

I am using `<a href="tel:12345678">Call me</a>` on web page to let user to call me when using mobile phone to view the page.

How can I count number of click on this href tag?  Please advise.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want to monitor how many users used this function.

Anyway, I had solved by using 'onclick' to trigger js function which will call another program to count.

```
 <a href='tel:12345678' onclick='addToCount(1);'>Call me</a>  

function addToCount(valueToAdd){

  // Do sth to call other program to store the new count
}
```

Comment: if you refresh the page.does it maintain all the counts?

Comment: you need to make an ajax call and save the count to database if you want to keep count of number of clicks